# Find an example of a group algebra with non-trivial solutions to $x^2=x$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, idempotents, group-rings

I am looking for a group-algebra with a non-trivial solution to $x^2=x$. That is to say, a solution with $x\neq 1$ and $x \neq 0$ where $1$ is the identity.

We have $x\subset \mathbb{C}[G]$ for some group $G$ and want to find some small group such that $x^2=x$ has non-trivial solutions.

Is this possible and if so can you give an example of such a group? A simple group if possible.

Comment: Try some examples yourself!  Literally any nontrivial finite group works.

Comment: What do you mean by simple group? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_group

Comment: @Eric. Hmm I got as far as complex numbers and the quaternion group and couldn't find anything. Maybe I missed something.

Comment: @Azlif the usual definition.

Comment: Hmm, maybe this question was too easy after all! Yes, I think even the group algebra $\mathbb{Z}_3$ will work!.

Comment: @EgoKilla: The group operation in $\mathbb{Z}_6$ is addition, not multiplication.  So multiplication in the group algebra corresponds to addition mod 6, not multiplication.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $G=\{1,g\}$ be cyclic of order $2$.  Then $x=\frac{1+g}{2}$ satisfies $$x^2=\frac{1}{4}(1+2g+g^2)=\frac{1}{4}(1+2g+1)=\frac{1+g}{2}=x.$$

Much more generally, it follows from the representation theory of finite groups that for any finite group $G$, $\mathbb{C}[G]$ is isomorphic to a product of matrix rings $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ for various values of $n$, with the number of factors in the product being the number of conjugacy classes in $G$.  It follows immediately that if $G$ is any nontrivial finite group then there are nontrivial solutions to $x^2=x$ in $\mathbb{C}[G]$, since you can take an element that is $1$ on some of the factors and $0$ on others.

Comment: What do you mean by non-trivial? The quaternion group is non-trivial so I would expect there to be non-trivial solution in quaternion algebra. Maybe I missed it.

Comment: Yes, there are plenty of solutions in the group algebra of the quaternion group.  Note that the group algebra of the quaternion group is _not_ the same thing as the usual algebra $\mathbb{H}$ of quaternions.

Comment: Hmm, I guess because $-1$ is an element of the quaternion group so any combination $a\mathbf{1}+(a-1)\mathbf{(-1)}$ is a solution as this is essentially 1.

Comment: yes, I meant when projecting the group algebra onto the quaternions many combinations project onto 1. Because (-1) is an element of the group.

Comment: No, that doesn't work.  Try squaring it: it won't work for most values of $a$.

Comment: Oh yeah. good point there.